# Change Audacity playback speed without affecting pitch

Tags: audacity, pitch, playback

Audacity's [Play-at-Speed Toolbar](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/play_at_speed_toolbar.html) enables one to change the playback speed, but is there a way of changing the playback speed without the pitch changing?

<sup>Changing [VLC's playback speed](https://wiki.videolan.org/Vlc_MacOS_Playback/) has no effect on its pitch.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audacity is rather simplistic in approach. It doesn't seem to have the subtlety required to do this in real-time.

It has an option - Effect > Change Tempo…
See the manual pages at - [Change Tempo](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_tempo.html)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only way.